# difference between resource model and model in magento

Tags: php, magento, difference

What is the difference between these two syntaxes?

1) `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('1');`

2) `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mage::getModel()**

Mage::getModel() will create a new instance of an object each time even such object exists in configuration.

Example

```
$product1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

$product1 and $product2 both have different instant of same object and also occupy different memory

**Mage::getResourceModel()**

As far as I know, all collections in Magento are resource models. They are instantiated by

```
Mage::getResourceModel()
```

or

```
Mage::getModel()->getCollection()
```

It doesn't really matter which function you use; the latter one simply calls the first one. The Magento team simply chose to make collections part of the resource, probably because collections need to query the database a lot. Usually, you will not have to call `Mage::getResourceModel()` for anything else than collections.

**See below link.**
http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm